# Github > Compil binaries from pull requests

Tags: java, github, compilation

I manage a java application. We use github.

I have 2 ways to deliver a project : I deliver all the project or I deliver only the source that changes (as a patch)

I would like to compil and generate .class files specific to a particular pull-request. Is it possible?

Thanks by advance!
lobrys

Answer (score 0):

It is posible. Do step by step:

1. New source code.
2. Copile all application.
3. List Java file(s) changed
4. Pick *.class appropriate file(s) (insite `target` folder what are
   just compiled)
5. Patch to a running application.

but, you shouldn't do this, for the stable of your application.